# Residue of function with expression and higher order pole

Tags: complex-analysis

Good evening! I'm stuck on calculating the residue at pole z=0

$\frac{e^z}{z^2(z-1)}$

So the expansion of $e^z$ = 1 + z + $\frac{z^2}{2}$ + $\frac{z^3}{3!}$...

the expansion of $\frac{1}{z-1}$ = -1 - z - $z^2$ - $z^3$...

$\frac{e^z}{z^2}$ gives us then $\frac{1}{z^2}$ + $\frac{1}{z}$ + $\frac{1}{2}$ + $\frac{z}{3!}$...

Which lead to ($\frac{1}{z^2}$ + $\frac{1}{z}$ + $\frac{1}{2}$ + $\frac{z}{3!}$...)( -1 - z - $z^2$ - $z^3$...) as a product of two expansions

How to find residue now? I'm missing something?

Comment: Find all multiplications that will result in a term $\frac{1}{z}$. Those are $\frac{1}{z^2}\cdot(-z)$, $\frac{1}{z}\cdot(-1)$ and add them.

Comment: Oh, so I need to add them. Thanks!